# Sagemath Graph Theory: is_perfect() returns false, even if clique number and chromatic number are equal

Tags: graph-theory, sage

The definition of a perfect graph is the following: Given a graph G. Then G is called perfect if its clique number and chromatic number are identical.

Now, I'm using sage math for calculating the chromatic number and the clique number of a given graph in graph6-format. It gives me strange results. Taking a simple triangle as a simple example, everything is correct.

```
G=Graph()
from_graph6(G,'Bw')

print(G.clique_number())
print(G.chromatic_number())
print(G.is_perfect())
```

The above code yields to

```
> 3
> 3
> True
```

However taking the graph "HCrfVY}" yields to

```
> 4
> 4
> False
```

Since 4=4, the call to "is_perfect()" should yield to True. What is going on here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That does not seem to be the standard definition of a perfect graph. The condition should apply to all induced subgraphs. For "HCrfVY}" this fails for two subgraphs, one of those is the one induced by vertices {1,2,4,5,6,7,8}. Further details at the sage cell server: https://x0.no/4tifz